# Bad SubDomain SQL query error with prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

My website shows an `Bad Sub Domain SOL query` error when visiting the site.

It's an E-commerce site, the used platform is PrestaShop(Version: 1.5.5.0) and it worked well in the last 2 years.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: Did you update the Software in the last time?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply,No i didn't update

Comment: It seems table `PREFIX_subdomain` is missing in your database. Can you check it under phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Do you have any error logs that you could look up?

Comment: Yes, we haved checked it already and it was there. So I deleted and added ps_subdomain (saw this step on different forum).

Comment: @AbdulMajidP You mean www entry is already there in ps_subdomain table? Are you able to provide url to check?

Comment: Yes, the entry was already there and we again added it after deleting. Here you go www.streamport.tv

Comment: @KhorneHoly: Error logs for last two days is "File does not exist" for  various pages on our site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Access cPanel > phpMyAdmin > your prestashop database ( _prestashop )?

2) Go to SQL tab and run the following query for database _prestashop:

```
CREATE TABLE ps_subdomain (
  id_subdomain int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
   name varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (id_subdomain)
) ENGINE=ENGINE_TYPE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After you have successfully recreated the table ps_subdomain, you need to insert [www] value with the below query:

```
INSERT INTO ps_subdomain (id_subdomain, name) VALUES (1, 'www');
```

It should fix the above error.

Comment: When I run the above code from SQL lab it gave me the below error. However, I have added the table and its properties by GUI.

MySQL said:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ps_subdomain' (
  'id_subdomain' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ' at line 1

Comment: @AbdulMajidP Have you copy-pasted the above query? Try to type and run it manually and see if it works.

Comment: G We run that code successfully, but the problem remains the same. Kindly give another solution urgently

Comment: I have same error can you tell me how you fix that error@AbdulMajidP